# How to restrict calling of methods by clients?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have below class with few public methods.

```
public class Sample{

  public void method1(){ }

  public void method2(){ }

  public void method3(){ }

  public void method4(){ }
}
```

I need to expose only first three methods to clients and not `method4()`. How can I create one more class exposing only the first 3 methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private

Comment: I cannot change to private. Because when i instantiate the same class, i should be able to call the method4.

Comment: Then what do you mean by not exposing it?

Comment: Do you want to create another class, e.g. `RestrictedSample`, that only offers access to methods 1-3?

Comment: Yes Duncan..u r right..

Comment: Can you make an example of what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a public class that offers methods 1-3 only, wrap `Sample` in another class like this:

```
public class RestrictedSample {

  private Sample sample = new Sample();

  public void method1(){ sample.method1(); }

  public void method2(){ sample.method2(); }

  public void method3(){ sample.method3(); }
}
```

This is known as the [façade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), or simply [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

Be warned: as long as `Sample` remains public, other code can construct instances of that class. That may not be a problem for you, but it's worth remembering.

Comment: Duncan, the idea is, through RestrictedSample class clients can set the data into sample object. Now how can i get the same sample object ? If i provide getter method then clients can access the sample object which i dont want to do.

Comment: @user755806 Provide setter methods in `RestrictedSample` that adjust the inner `sample` instance.

Comment: then how can i get the data which is in sample instance?

Comment: @user755806 Provide getter methods!

Answer (score 2):

create an interface which expose only 3 methods:

```
public interface ISample{
  public void method1();
  public void method2();
  public void method3();
}
```

Let the class implement it:

```
public class Sample implement ISample {
 // all method definitions are not changed
}
```

When you need full access, use type `Sample`, when restricted, then `ISample`:

```
Sample sample=new Sample();
sample.method4();
passToUser((ISample)sample);
```

Comment: I'm guessing `passToUser` takes `ISample` instances? If so, the cast is unnecessary. Note also that the `I` prefix is very common in .NET, but generally not used in Java.

Comment: This approach is also flawed, because the code receiving the `ISample` instance can cast it to `Sample` and access the hidden method.

Comment: @Duncan malicious client can read RestrictedSample.sample from your variant using reflection, Unsafe, or JNI. We don't know required defense level - maybe my variant is OK, maybe your variant is insecure.

Comment: That's a fair point. Perhaps I was too strong with my wording (r.e 'flawed'). However, I think it's worth noting that a simple cast overcomes this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Better control over scope of visibility  is one of the major things OSGi adds to Java. If this is a serious project, you may want to consider investing in learning OSGi.

If this is just something you're doing for yourself, or for class, you may want to consider something weaker but simpler such as marking the method deprecated or just renaming it to INTERNAL_USE_ONLY_method4.

Or leave the method as "package" access.